# Prototype Selector Problem IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I have a validation class that uses the following CSS selector (Prototype 1.6.1):

```
$$('*[class*=validate]')
```

The idea is I have various class names for elements that start with 'validate', ie 'validate-numeric' or 'validate-url'.  So, I'd like to grab any element with the word validate in the class attribute.

It works in just about any other browser, including IE 6 & 7.  In IE 8, it doesn't seem to select the proper elements.  I tried to do some debugging in IE's developer tools, but the console, in all it's wisdom, only outputs {...} for arrays and objects.  Is there something I am missing?  Yes, it's a CSS3 selector, but I thought it was still implemented in Prototype and 6 & 7 both worked with it.

Comment: if you're stopped at a breakpoint you can use the Watch window in IE's console to look at object properties.

Comment: Are you using http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation? If not then consider it, it will save you the trouble of reinventing another wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't figured out, here's an alternative. Classify all your elements as such:

```
<div class="validate numeric">foo</div>
<div class="validate url">bar</div>
<div class="validate email">world</div>
```

Then this surely will work in IE8:

```
$$('.validate');
```

I'm guessing you're writing some code for form validation and these are errors that could occur. The CSS for my schema would be

```
.validate { color: red }
.numeric { margin: 1px }
.url { margin: 2px; }
.email { padding: 3px; }
```

Whereas your CSS schema wouldn't be modular - thus making it hard to maintain as your add more and more error types.

```
.validate_numeric,
.validate_url,
.validate_email {
 color: red;
}

.validate_numeric { margin: 1px }
.validate_url { margin: 2px; }
.validate_email { padding: 3px; }
```